# sending email with attachment from Azure using SendGrid

Tags: asp.net, vba, azure, sendgrid

How do I send an email with an attachment using SendGrid, from my VM in Azure?

I added   `myMsg.AddAttachment` and supplied the parameters.  I get no errors when I execute, but Email never gets sent.  If I comment out this line,
email gets sent.

What am I doing wrong?  This is in ASP.net VB.

Comment: Look at the delivery reports in SendGrid's portal, there's probably a bounce from the recipient's MX, the reason should be in there.

Comment: If there is more information about reproduced code sample and detail exception will be more helpful.

Comment: What is the filesize of that attachment (maybe there are limits on that)

Comment: It is a small Excel file.  Size should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Sendgrid 9.9.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/9.9.0/) to check this issue, here is the code snippet:

```
'instantiate the SendGridMessage object 
Dim sendGridMessage = New SendGridMessage()
sendGridMessage.From = New EmailAddress("xxxxxx@hotmail.com", "BruceChen1019")
sendGridMessage.AddTo(New EmailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com", "Bruce Chen"))
sendGridMessage.PlainTextContent = "Hello World!"
sendGridMessage.Subject = "Hello Email!"

'instantiate the Attachment object
Dim attachment = New Attachment()
attachment.Filename = "helloword.txt"
attachment.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello world!!!"))
attachment.Type = "text/plain"
Dim attachments = New List(Of Attachment)
attachments.Add(attachment)
sendGridMessage.AddAttachments(attachments)

'send the email
Dim Response = client.SendEmailAsync(sendGridMessage).Result
Console.WriteLine(Response.StatusCode) //202 Accepted

Console.ReadLine()
```

**TEST:**

[image]

Moreover, for your attachment file, you need to set the correct MIME Type for `attachment.Type` based on the file extension, and Base64 encode your file content.

Also, you need to follow the [Attachments limitations](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Add_Content/attachments.html). And you may follow evilSnobu's comment about going to SendGrid portal for troubleshooting this issue.